# insert data into database in framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-insert

I am new one to codeigniter. I need to insert the data in the database for that i create a controller on the name Home.php, below is that code;While i am running i am getting the error like Message: Undefined property: Home::$Yes.Kindly help please,thank in advance

```
 <?php
   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
   class Home extends CI_Controller{
        public function index()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('yes');

    }
    public function savedata()
    {
        $this->load->view('demo');
        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $content=$this->input->post('content');
        $this->Yes->saverecords($name,$email,$content);     
        echo "Records Saved Successfully";
         }
         }
          }
```

Here the view pahe at name - demo.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"  
 id="User">     


               <h2 align="center">Student Marks</h2>
               <h3>Name:</h3>               
               <input type="text" name="name" />        
               <h3>Email ID</h3> 
               <input type="text" name="email" />       
               <h3>Content </h3>  
               <input type="text" name="content" />   


        <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" >Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" value="Reset" >Reset</button> 


        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the model page at Yes.php

```
<?php
class Yes extends CI_Models
{
    function saverecords($name,$email,$content)
    {
    $query="insert into news values('$name','$email','$mobile')";
    $this->db->query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Prem In Home Controller Edit a model like this 
$this->load->model('Yes', 'yes'); then alias yes use in  savedata() function. Thanks

Comment: Just to let you know CI_Models should be CI_Model https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#what-is-a-model

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you**

In controller load `database` and `model` in `__construct` like this , your are adding it to only `index` method

```
public function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->database();
   $this->load->model('yes');
}

public function index()
{
}

public function savedata()
{
    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    {
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $content = $this->input->post('content');

        $data = ['name' => $name,'email' => $email,'content' => $content];
        $insert_id = $this->yes->saverecords($data); 
        if ($insert_id)
        {
            echo "Records Saved Successfully";
        }    

    }
    $this->load->view('demo');
}
```

**Second**

Is `$this->load->view('demo');`  your form in `savedata()` method then the form url is ok but if not
Form action should redirect to `savedata` method because you are accessing post value to in it

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url('home/savedata');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Third Your Model should be like this:

```
<?php
class Yes extends CI_Models
{
    function saverecords($data)
    {
       $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
       return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to load model in your controller.

```
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
   class Home extends CI_Controller{
 function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Yes');

    }
 public function savedata()
    {
        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
       insert_array=array(
'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'content' => $this->input->post('content')
);
$data_id = $this->Yes->saverecords($insert_array);
if($data_id >0){
echo "Records Saved Successfully";
}
         }
         }
}
```

**In Model**

```
function saverecords($insert_array) {
        if ($this->db->insert('news', $insert_array)) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```